# How to control which window is opened as "other Window"?

Tags: spacemacs, magit, window

I am new to Magit and Spacemacs.
I do not understand descriptions of other-window and next-window in the manual.

I have 4 windows open in a Spacemacs frame like this:

```
+--+--+
|  |  |
+--+--+
|  |  |
+--+--+
```

`SPC g s` opens Magit Status in another window.
But which window?  It seems so random, with Magit Status often opening in a window I want left as is.

Is there a way to control which window `SPC g s` will open Magit Status?

Is there a way to predict which window `SPC g s` will open Magit Status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control how Magit selects a window to display a certain buffer using the option `magit-display-buffer-function` as described in [Switching Buffers](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Switching-Buffers.html). Unfortunately this is a rather complicated matter and it is not possible to come up with a solution that works for everyone (for Magit buffers or in Emacs in general). You should also consult the documentation that the linked resource itself links to.